# Make an answer duplicate

Tags: feature-request

You probably know about question duplicates.
I was thinking you could take that scenario, except in answers to try to prevent spam answers and exact duplicates of an answer that already answered the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the exact situation you mean, respectively give example links please?

Comment: @user0042 Ok, this is one where I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390063/what-does-public-static-void-mean-in-java/46017141#46017141

Comment: That doesn't work because *you* wrote a duplicate answer

Comment: Why on earth did you post that answer? Does it add anything that wasn't already said there?

Comment: @AnthonyPham why doesn't it, look at how many answers there are, and they are all the same.

Comment: Which were said were duplicate. Your post is now attracting downvotes and flags. Infinite wrongs don't make a right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate answers need to be removed or changed to be different.

The OP of the apparent "original" answer can either:

- Comment under the dupe answer and explain why the post is a duplicate and thus needs to removed or changed
- If the above is unsuccessful or it is very unclear who posted first, then maybe the user can:

  - Discuss the situation in chat with the other answerer
  - Or if required, request the intervention of a moderator via flagging and using the custom reason

The first option used on a duplicate answer is seen here:

[image]

Comment: the first what?

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2 The first option that I mentioned is being used in the screenshot